# Why am I unable to import my main.jsx file while starting my react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, watchify, babelify

This is the first react app i am trying to make but i am stuck with this error. the file structure seems to be correct and also my starting point.Please help me figure it out why it cannot find main.jsx module .

**file structure**

```
react-skeleton
 |
 +-- node_modules
 |    
 +-- public
 |  |  
 |  +-- js
 |  |    |
 |  |    +-- main.js
 |  |
 |  +--index.html
 |
 +-- src
 |  |  
 |  |  
 |  +-- components
 |  |    |
 |  |    +-- List.jsx
 |  |    |
 |  |    +-- Listitem.jsx
 |  |
 |  +--main.jsx
 |
 |    
 +-- package.json
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CommonJS React skeleton</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ingredients">

        </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**List.jsx**

```
    var React = require('react');
var ListItem = require('./Listitem.jsx');

var ingredients = [{"id":1, "text":"ham"},{"id":2, "text":"cheese"},{"id":3, "text":"potato"}];

var List = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var listItems = ingredients.map(function(item){
            return <ListItem key={item.id} ingredient  = {item.text} />;
        });

        return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
    }
});

module.exports = List;
```

**Listitem.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    return (
        <li>
            <h4>{this.props.ingredient}</h4>
        </li>
    );
    }
});

module.exports = ListItem;
```

**main.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
  var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
  var List = require('./components/List.jsx');

  ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('ingredients'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-skeleton",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "watchify ./src/main.jsx -v  -t [babelify --presets [ react ] ] -o ./public/js/main.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/SoeRatch/react-skeleton.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/SoeRatch/react-skeleton/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/SoeRatch/react-skeleton#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

I run it on my terminal using **npm start** and the error on my terminal is this:

```
    > react-skeleton@1.0.0 start /home/suraj/Desktop/REACTJS/project/react-skeleton
    > watchify src/main.jsx -v  -t [babelify --presets [ react ] ] -o public/js/main.js

Error: Cannot find module '/home/suraj/Desktop/REACTJS/project/react-skeleton/src/main.jsx' from '/home/suraj/Desktop/REACTJS/project/react-skeleton'
```

Comment: I have just recreated this in my local machine, it is working fine.

Comment: Is there a file called `npm-debug.log` ? Can you post the content of that file ?

Comment: I have package-lock.json

Comment: how can i get npm-debug.log file ? @FiriceNguyen

Comment: @Suraj: if you don't have it in your folder so the bug seems does not relate to `npm`. I clone your code and it works fine in my local environment. Are you sure you are using latest `node` and `npm` ?

Comment: my node version is 8.2.1 and npm 5.3.0 @FiriceNguyen

Comment: @Suraj: how about switch to the latest LTS `node` version 6.11.2 ?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen upgraded to 6.11.2 . still not happening